# Difference-in-differences Matching

Tags: econometrics, stata

I have a difference-in-differences analysis. My treatment is at the county level. Each county received the treatment at a certain point in time.

I want to proceed with a propensity score matching as an extension to get DiD-matching results . I know everything about PSM, however, I am not quite sure how to get the STATA command in order to:

1. Generate Pre- and Post-treatment dummies since I don't have a
   treatment at one point in time; i.e. DD is staggered.
2. Use the DD with [pscore](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0026)

Comment: What is the name of the time variable, and what range of values does it take on? Which year or month is the treatment done in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mark`. For example, if the treatment was done in the year 2000, and your time variable is called `time`, the syntax is

`mark treatment if time >= 2000 & time <.`

where `treatment` is the dummy that is generated.